# Piecewise and Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Assumptions sometimes work as expected with Piecewise, for example

```
 Simplify[Piecewise[{{A, a + b >= c}, {B, True}}], Assumptions -> a + b > c]
```

correctly yields the symbol A.

But sometimes they do not work as expected, for example

```
 Simplify[Piecewise[{{A, a b + c d >= e f}, {B, True}}], Assumptions -> a b + c d > e f]
```

yields a Piecewise expression with both pieces even though the Assumptions clearly preclude B. Is there some way to help Simplify along in cases like this?

Comment: Has nothing to do with Piecewise. The first works because `Simplify[a + b >= c, a + b > c]` returns True, while the second fails because `Simplify[a b + c d >= e f, a b + c d > e f]` returns unsimplified.